# Exporting zonal statistics attribute table from QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, zonal-statistics, save, uri

I have two layers: one is solar radiation, one is town boundaries. I used zonal statistics and seem to have correctly generated that.

I'm able to view the attribute table and all seems to be in order. However, if I try to "save as" or "export" in csv, xlsx, or txt format, I get the error message

> Error: Storing metadata for the specified uri is not supported.

How do I resolve this? I tried to copy and paste the data from the attribute table into Excel, but the format changed to the point where it wasn't usable anymore.

Edit: I'm using "Zonal statistics" from the toolbox. My input layer is the borders (ESRI Shapefile) and the raster layer is an asc file of solar values. If I try to save as GeoPackage, error is "unable to open database file." Saving as Excel or other file "The layer was not correctly generated."

Comment: what happens if you first export it as shape/geopackage and then save this file as CSV?

Comment: I just ran zonal statistics and exported the results to csv with no issues.  Suggest you edit your question and specify exactly what you did (which zonal statistics tool, exactly what parameters, how you tried to export)

Comment: @user2856 edited my post to reflect these.

Comment: @sn1ks The stats weren't created, see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Resolved: it was an error with the border geometry, so first I needed to run "Fix geometries" from the processing toolbox.